# HibernateTemplate vs SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

Maybe someone could explain which one to use? When and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [javadoc of HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) says:

> NOTE: As of Hibernate 3.0.1, transactional Hibernate access code can
>   also be coded in plain Hibernate style. Hence, for newly started
>   projects, consider adopting the standard Hibernate3 style of coding
>   data access objects instead, based on
>   SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

So even Spring tells you not to use Spring's HibernateTemplate anymore. And there is no HibernateTemplate for Hibernate4. The choice should be obvious.

Comment: what about "It provides Hibernate Session handling such that neither the HibernateCallback implementation nor the calling code needs to explicitly care about retrieving/closing Hibernate Sessions, or handling Session lifecycle exceptions" ? Would it be easier on our part to handle sessions properly ?

Comment: All you need to do, without HibernateTemplate, is to call sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). The rest is handled by Spring.

Comment: Cool. However, I suppose session factory.getCurrentSession requires an active spring transaction. For create/update operation we have transactions.. But for select operation we have to unnecessarily create the transactions. Do you have any workaround for this?

Comment: It's far from being unnecessary to have transactions: they're needed to get attached objects where lazy-loading works, and they ensure the data is consistent between several reads, and they allow benefitting from the first-level cache. What makes you think transactions are a problem? They're not. Having transactions will make your code faster, not slower.

Comment: Yeah ... Transactions are not a problem actually.